# Criação de uma State Machine sem bibliotecas no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, máquina-de-estado

Estava procurando como programar uma *state machine* no google e cheguei a vários resultados que me levavam a bibliotecas direcionadas a tal, mas gostaria de entender a forma que ela é processada e como chegar a uma *state machine* simples e funcional.

Pretendo utilizar ela para um jogo de turno simples no elemento canvas, sou iniciante na área e gostaria de qualquer ajuda que eu pudesse receber, grato!

Comment: Que tipo de máquina de estados você quer? Um autômato de estados finito?

Comment: maquina de estados finita

Answer (score 4):

Uma máquina de estados finito é uma máquina com um conjunto finito de estados (como o nome já diz). Ela é modelada como um grafo, no qual os vértices são os estados e as arestas são as transições. Para uma dada entrada partindo-se de um determinado estado, chega-se em um outro estado.

Um dos estados da máquina de estados é denominado de estado inicial. Então para cada símbolo de entrada, você navega nas transições de um estado para outro. Observe que a única coisa que é memorizada é o estado atual.

Implementando isso, talvez o que você queira seja algo assim:

```js
function MaquinaDeEstados() {
  var estados = new Map();

  var erro = {
    adicionarTransicao: function(entrada, destino) {
      return this;
    },
    proximo: function(entrada) {
      return erro;
    },
    valor: function() {
      return "{erro}";
    }
  };

  function Estado(valor) {
    var transicoes = new Map();
  
    this.adicionarTransicao = function(entrada, destino) {
      transicoes.set(entrada, destino);
      return this;
    };

    this.proximo = function(entrada) {
      var retorno = transicoes.get(entrada);
      return typeof retorno === "undefined" ? erro : retorno;
    };

    this.valor = function() {
      return valor;
    };
  }

  this.estado = function(chave) {
    var estado = estados.get(chave);
    if (typeof estado === "undefined") {
      estado = new Estado(chave);
      estados.set(chave, estado);
    }
    return estado;
  };
}

/* Teste. Criando uma máquina de estados: */
var chave1 = "A", chave2 = "B", chave3 = "C";
var maquina = new MaquinaDeEstados();
var estado1 = maquina.estado(chave1);
var estado2 = maquina.estado(chave2);
var estado3 = maquina.estado(chave3);
estado1.adicionarTransicao(0, estado1);
estado1.adicionarTransicao(1, estado2).adicionarTransicao(2, estado3);
estado2.adicionarTransicao(3, estado3).adicionarTransicao(2, estado3);
estado3.adicionarTransicao(1, estado1);

/* Teste. Executando a máquina de estados: */
var entrada = [0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, "lugar nenhum", 2, 2];
var atual = estado1; // Definimos que este é o estado inicial.
var passeio = atual.valor();
for (k in entrada) {
  var v = entrada[k];
  atual = atual.proximo(v);
  passeio += " " + atual.valor();
}

document.write(passeio);
```

No código de teste, você notará a seguinte entrada:

```
[0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, "lugar nenhum", 2, 2]
```

Se você clicar no botão azul <kbd>► Executar</kbd> que está acima, ele vai te mostrar isso:

```
A A B C A A C A {erro} {erro} {erro}
```

Inicialmente ele estava no estado A (estado inicial). Ao receber o 0, ele continuou no estado A. Ao receber o 1, ele foi para o estado B. Do estado B ao receber 3 ele foi para o estado C, e então voltou ao A com 1.

Se uma entrada inválida for dada, tal como o `"lugar nenhum"` do exemplo, então ele vai para o estado de erro, de onde ele nunca sai.

Observe também que a própria máquina de estados não armazena qual é o estado atual. O estado atual é mantido em uma variável fora da máquina, pelo código que a está percorrendo. Isso permite que possamos começar a iteração a partir de qualquer estado, não necessariamente o estado inicial, e também permite que vários códigos possam iterar uma mesma máquina em partes diferentes sem um interferir com o outro. Aliás, isso também permite que não precisemos nem mesmo armazenar dentro da máquina qual é o estado inicial, vez que podemos começar do estado que quisermos. Se um estado inicial é obrigatório, basta começarmos sempre do mesmo estado como o exemplo faz.

Comment: +1 pela explicação. Só achei a falta da explicação do que é "State Machine", tanto na pergunta tanto na resposta.

Comment: @Randrade Aumentei a explicação e simplifiquei também um pouco o javascript.

Comment: Para mim está "perfeito" agora!

Comment: compreendi o funcionamento da state machine, mas fiquei um pouco confuso com o código, mas muito obrigado foi de grande ajuda